# Get all links begin with

Tags: java, selenium, webdriver, selenium-webdriver

I'm trying to get all links on a webpage, that begin with, like:

`http://www.teste.com/test1`

As you see, i need get all links that have at least **http:\www.teste.com\test**

I tried do with:

`List<WebElement> ee = driver.findElements(By.partialLinkText("http://www.teste.com/test"));`

But nothing return..

Any tip?

Answer (score 1):

You need to use XPath or CssSelector for this.

Without seeing your HTML, I assume you have something like

```
<a href="http://www.teste.com/test">Test</a>
```

Then use XPath or CssSelector

```
List<WebElement> usingXPath = driver.findElements(By.xpath(".//a[starts-with(@href, 'http://www.teste.com/test')]"));
List<WebElement> usingCssSelector = driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("a[href^='http://www.teste.com/test']"));
```

Comment: @user3062055: Looks like you have never accepted any answers before. Since this answer fixes your issue, please consider accepting it. (http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/220697)

Answer (score 0):

If your link texts(not the href) that are displayed in page look like Test1 , Test2 etc... then you can use `List<WebElement> ee = driver.findElements(By.partialLinkText("Test"));`